# Symfony get connected user id from entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony2.8/Doctrine2 application, I need to store in each row of my SQL tables the id of the user who created or updated the row (users can connect with Ldap).

So all my entities inherited of a `GenericEntity` which contains this variable (type would be string if I want to store Ldap username):

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zzCreationId", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $creationId;
```

And I use the `prePersistCallback()` to automatically assign this value:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function prePersistCallback()
{
    $currentUser = /* ...... ????? ....... */ ;
    if ($currentUser->getId() != null) {
        $this->creationId = $currentUser->getId() ;
    } else {
        $this->creationId = 'unknown' ;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve the connected user, or how to automatically inject it in the entity... How can I do it?

Comment: You have to add a relation between you User entity and your GenericEntity

Comment: @DOZ My users are connected through Ldap, I need to retreive it from security context. But how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Doctrine entity listener/subscriber instead to inject the security token and get the current logged user:

```
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/EntityListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\GenericEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class EntityListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage = null) 
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        // only act on "GenericEntity"
        if (!$entity instanceof GenericEntity) {
            return;
        }

        if (null !== $currentUser = $this->getUser()) {
            $entity->setCreationId($currentUser->getId());
        } else {
            $entity->setCreationId(0);
        }
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        if (!$this->tokenStorage) {
            throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application.');
        }

        if (null === $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
            // e.g. anonymous authentication
            return;
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Next register your listener:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    my.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\EntityListener
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

Comment: Your solution seems the closest I need. I tried to implement it but unfortunately, my `creationId` field, inherited from a `GenericEntity` which is a `MappedSuperclass`, is not present in my child Entity, and the event is only fired with my child entity without the `MappedSuperclass` fields. So the PrePersist has no effect. Note that if I use PrePersistCallback in my GenericEntity, the fields exists...

Comment: My bad, I updated my answer using setter, this must be able in you child entity. However, feel free to change the target entity.

Comment: I only add, that *it's very important to implement `getUser()` functionality exactly not in `__construct()`*, 'cause otherwise `$token` is empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`@ORM\PrePersist` and other callback methods used in the entity are suppose to contain simple logic and be independant of other services.

You need to create event listener or subscriber to listen `postPersist` doctrine event and fill in corresponding attribute. Check [How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at BlameableListener from gedmo/doctrine-extensions package, that work almost the way you want but with the username instead of the user id.