# symfony 3 Doctrine LIstener service inject token_storage doesnt work

Tags: php, doctrine, listener, symfony

I have a doctrine listener which needs the get the current logged in user.

```
class DoctrineListener
{
    /**
     * @var null|TokenInterface
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * DoctrineListener constructor.
     *
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->token = $tokenStorage->getToken();

        var_dump($this->token);
    }
```

and in my service.yml:

```
doctrine.listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\DoctrineListener
    arguments:
      - '@security.token_storage'
    public: false
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preFlush, method: preFlush }
```

The dump always returns me null when I try to use it in this listener.
I inject the token_storage_service in other services and it works well.

I'm under symfony 3.1, with a rest API.
And i send my authorizations header with Postman.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332767/symfony-get-connected-user-id-from-entity

Comment: it returns null because the security listener isn't (yet) executed

Comment: Thanks @Al Fonce, this did help me too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `$tokenStorage->getToken()` in you preFlush method not in the constructor.

Comment: This is it. Thanks to you and @Frederico.